# Android PocketSphinx: Language model files not written when installed from the apk

Tags: android

PocketSphinx works fine. Have also created some specialized voice command dictionaries.
When I installed PocketSphinx the instructions said to create edu.cmu.pocketsphinx and subfolders under /sdcard/android/data on my device. And the language models and dics are present.
App is working fine.

Problem: I have created the apk and sent it to my brother for testing and it chrashes when the recognition starts. I suspected rightly that the edu.cmu.pocketsphinx-folder had not been created on my brother's phone.
I sent him the edu.cmu.pocketsphinx-folder to install manually and it works. But not optimal for a downloader to fiddle with files like that.

Questions:
Is there a way to auto-get-folder-installed?
Something to do with a build path? 
Some wrapping, perhaps?

If any of you have experience with exporting pocketsphinxdemo to apk could you please tell me about the trickery associated with it?

Hope this is not too vague.

I am in dire need.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Here's one suggestion:

Save the files in res/raw/.
When the app starts check if the files have been saved to the sdcard,
if not then copy them from res/raw.

In the sdcard, you could use a directory name with a version string included,
that way it will be straight-forward to update.